# Create dummy variable across multiple columns by group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have data in a household roster as in the dataframe below

```
hhroster <- data.frame(HHID = c(1, 1,   1,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4,  5,  5,  6),                     
                    INDID = c(1,    2,  3,  1,  2,  1,  2,  3,  4,  1,  2,  3,  1,  2,  1),
                    response_1 = c("yes",   "no",   "yes",  "yes",  "no",   "no",   "no",   "no",   "no",   "yes",  "yes",  "no",   "yes",  "yes",  "no"),
                    response_2 = c("no",    "no",   "yes",  "no",   "no",   "no",   "yes",  "no",   "no",   "no",   "no",   "no",   "yes",  "yes",  "no"))
```

and would like to create a dummy variable at household level with the value 1 indicating there was at least one yes response from an individual. The desired output is

```
hh <- data.frame(HHID = c(1,    2,  3,  4,  5,  6),
                       HH_response_1 = c(1, 1,  0,  1,  1,  0),
                       HH_response_2 = c(1, 0,  1,  0,  1,  0))
```

Add: I have realized the dataset has values such as DK, RF and missing values and would like if a household has all its values among these the aggregate value should be NA and not 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution.
Use `across` to get all columns of interest and check if there are any yes values by checking if the sum of logical values `.x == "yes"` is greater than zero.
You can keep the results as logical, R will coerce `F/T` to `0/1` if and when necessary.

```r
hhroster <- data.frame(HHID = c(1, 1,   1,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4,  5,  5,  6),                     
                       INDID = c(1,    2,  3,  1,  2,  1,  2,  3,  4,  1,  2,  3,  1,  2,  1),
                       response_1 = c("yes",   "no",   "yes",  "yes",  "no",   "no",   "no",   "no",   "no",   "yes",  "yes",  "no",   "yes",  "yes",  "no"),
                       response_2 = c("no",    "no",   "yes",  "no",   "no",   "no",   "yes",  "no",   "no",   "no",   "no",   "no",   "yes",  "yes",  "no"))

suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(dplyr)
)

hhroster %>%
  summarise(
    across(starts_with("response"), ~ sum(.x == "yes") > 0L),
    .by = HHID
  )
#>   HHID response_1 response_2
#> 1    1       TRUE       TRUE
#> 2    2       TRUE      FALSE
#> 3    3      FALSE       TRUE
#> 4    4       TRUE      FALSE
#> 5    5       TRUE       TRUE
#> 6    6      FALSE      FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Here is a variation with `max`: `summarise(across(starts_with("response"), ~max(as.integer(. == "yes"))))`

Comment: code golf: `~ +("yes" %in% .x)` to get 1s and 0s, otherwise `~ "yes" %in% .x` returns a `logical`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `aggregate`

```
> aggregate(. ~ HHID, hhroster[-2], \(x) +any(x == "yes"))
  HHID response_1 response_2
1    1          1          1
2    2          1          0
3    3          0          1
4    4          1          0
5    5          1          1
6    6          0          0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr` package, you could do something like this

```r
library(dplyr)

hh <- hhroster |>
  mutate(
    response_1_logic = ifelse(response_1 == "yes", TRUE, FALSE),
    response_2_logic = ifelse(response_2 == "yes", TRUE, FALSE)
  ) |>
  summarise(
    HH_response_1 = as.numeric(any(response_1_logic)),
    HH_response_2 = as.numeric(any(response_2_logic)),
    .by = HHID
  )
```

output

```
> hh
  HHID HH_response_1 HH_response_2
1    1             1             1
2    2             1             0
3    3             0             1
4    4             1             0
5    5             1             1
6    6             0             0
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(dplyr)

hhroster %>% 
  reframe(across(response_1:response_2, ~ +any(.x == "yes")), .by = HHID)

#>   HHID response_1 response_2
#> 1    1          1          1
#> 2    2          1          0
#> 3    3          0          1
#> 4    4          1          0
#> 5    5          1          1
#> 6    6          0          0
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>